# Como redirecionar para auth/login no Laravel 5.1 se o visitante não estiver autenticado?

Tags: laravel, autenticação, laravel-5, redirecionamento

Estou usando a autenticação nativa do Laravel 5.1 mas ao acessar uma rota protegida o sistema não me redireciona para a tela de login, ao invés disso ela me mostra a mensagem "You don't have permission to access this resource".

As rotas então desse jeito:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','before' => 'auth','middleware'=>['needsRole:Admin'],'namespace'=>'Admin'], function()
{
    Route::resource('/', 'HomeController');
    Route::resource('users','UsersController');
    Route::resource('stores','StoresController');
    Route::resource('templates','TemplatesController');
});
```

Comment: Você tem que fazer isso pelo Middleware. Qual você está utilizando ?

Comment: As rotas então desse jeito: http://pastebin.com/EK4JYx7Y

Comment: Beleza, mas e a Middleware ? `'auth','middleware'=>['needsRole:Admin']`. O que tem nessa **Middleware** ? Ela que vai redirecionar o usuário.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava comentendo um erro:

```
['prefix'=>'admin','before' => 'auth','middleware'=>['needsRole:Admin'],'namespace'=>'Admin']
```

Quando na verdade é:

```
['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>['auth','needsRole:Admin'],'namespace'=>'Admin']
```